# Is this argument valid?

Tags: logic

Is this argument valid?

> 

1. No one under  18 is  permitted  to vote.
2. No faculty  member  is  under  18.
3. The  philosophy chairperson is  a  faculty member.
4. Conclusion: The philosophy  chairperson  is permitted  to  vote.

Was my answer not valid because  the conclusion  doesn't  follow from the premises?

Comment: Wait. Philosophy chairperson is a faculty member -> philosophy chairperson is 18 years old or older -> philosophy chairperson is permitted to vote. The argument is sound. And "the conclusion don't follow from the premises." is not what validity means.

Comment: I'm sorry, to avoid gamesmanship here on the forum... are you asking about the argument ending in "Then the philosophy chairperson..." ? or the one ending in "My answer was it is not..."?

Comment: I'm  asking if my answer  was correct  or not

Comment: What you might need to add is why the conclusion does not follow from the premises, not just assert that it doesn't follow from the premises. What were your reasons? Welcome to this SE!

Comment: This is the recurrent question type (RQT) [“Is X valid?”](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5658/recurrent-question-type-rqt-is-x-valid). I invite anyone to discuss or analyze how such questions may be improved at the link provided.

Comment: The specific reason the conclusion doesn't follow from the premises is because there are other reasons to not be able to vote. So "I'm under 18 implies I can't vote" still leaves open other things, like for example "I'm not a citizen so I can't vote". We know the chairperson is over 18, but we don't know if there's possibly another reason he wouldn't be able to vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument is invalid. In fact, it's an instance of the fallacy of [denying the antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent).

To see this, we can formalize the argument as follows:

> 1. Under-18 → not Permitted
> 2. Faculty → not Under-18
> 3. Chair is Faculty

From 2 and 3 we can deduce that Chair is not under 18. But we cannot then deduce from this and 1 that Chair is permitted to vote: that would commit the fallacy of denying the antecedent.

Another way to see that the argument is invalid is to imagine a scenario where the premises are true and the conclusion is false. For example, the chairperson might not be permitted to vote because they are not a citizen (which isn't ruled out by the premises). If it's possible for the premises to be true and the conclusion false, then the argument is invalid.

Comment: I used the star test by Harry j. Gensler  and that's  why  my answer  was invalid.

Answer (score 3):

I arrived at the same conclusion (invalidity) as Eliran H, but for a different reason. The premises are insufficient to show, affirmatively, that persons 18 years old and older are permitted to vote. Missing that information, the reasoning fails.

Here are my notes on my attempt to reason it through:

1. If Person is Underage, then they are not permitted to Vote.

1.1 If Person is permitted to Vote, then they are not Underage. Contrapositive of #1 (looking for an affirmative statement about voting).

2. If Person is Faculty, then they are not Underage.
3. If Person is Chairperson, then they are Faculty.

Partial (valid) Conclusion: If Person is Chairperson, then they are not Underage. (#2 + #3)

4. Final (failed) Conclusion: If Person is Chairperson, then they are permitted to Vote.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it as valid but I believe it WOULD be valid if you said EVERYONE over 18 is permitted to vote.

For instance, you could say the chairperson already voted once and is not allowed to vote again.  In that case the first 3 premises are satisfied but the conclusion is not.  But if everyone over 18 was permitted, he could vote again even though he already voted once.  Unless you added another axiom saying someone could vote only once.